# Basic grouping within a window function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am working with window functions for the first time. I have a basic window function, I'd like to group the results by Medium, when I do this I get the error:

`Error: SELECT list expression references totals.visits which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [1:12]`

To my mind, I have summed totals.visits on the first row, what am I missing here? I would like to see the total number of visits broken down by country, for example:

```
VISITS          COUNTRY
1500            United Kingdom
750             Ireland
etc.
```

Here is my query:

```
 SELECT
        SUM(totals.visits) OVER(PARTITION BY geoNetwork.country
                                ORDER BY geoNetwork.country) AS Visits_by_Medium,
        trafficSource.medium AS Medium
    FROM `xxx.ga_sessions_20171010`
    GROUP BY Medium
```

Comment: select fields should be in the group by, try that

Comment: If I add Visits_by_Medium to the GROUP BY I get: Error: Column Visits_by_Medium contains an analytic function, which is not allowed in GROUP BY at [3:18]

Comment: Your use of an analytic function implies that you want every record in your table returned, while the `GROUP BY` implies that you want an aggregate.  Please show us your expected output.

Comment: You don't have to group by the sum, just trafficSource.medium (try without the alias) and sorry I thought I have read another field in the select, now it is clearer to read

Comment: @MiloBellano GROUP BY trafficSource.medium returns the same error as the alias.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I have added an example output to my question, hopefully this explains more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want a simple `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT
    SUM(totals.visits) AS VISITS,
    geoNetwork.country
FROM xxx.ga_sessions_20171010
GROUP BY
    geoNetwork.country;
```

**Edit:**

Run the following query to see what sum as a window function will return you:

```
SELECT
    SUM(totals.visits) OVER(PARTITION BY geoNetwork.country
                            ORDER BY geoNetwork.country) AS Visits_by_Medium,
    trafficSource.medium AS Medium
FROM xxx.ga_sessions_20171010;
```

Comment: Thank you, this does answer the question, however I was trying explore a use case for window functions in my data - can you explain why the SUM aggregation isn't working?

Comment: @BenP AFAIK your query makes no sense.  The window function returns every row in your table, hence you would not get one record per country, you'd get _every_ record for each country.  Use `GROUP BY` if you really want to aggregate, which seems to be your use case.

Comment: Okay looks like I started with a poor example of using the window. Thanks for your help.